# Aiogram + selenium

Tags: python, aiogram, selenium, threading

Есть тг бот, который отвечает на команды /start и тд. А еще есть код на селениуме который просто в цикле ходит по страницам(и плюсом в седениуме нужно отправлять сообщение в тг бота).Если запустить все вместе то тг будет блокироваться, так как селениум же не асинхронный. Задача: чтобы все работало вместе

Как это рализовать через потоки?

````
from config import API_TOKEN
from selenium import webdriver
import asyncio
from aiogram import executor

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(user_id, "Старт")

            
async def main(bot):
    await bot.send_message(user_id, "Запустил бот")
    while True:
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main(bot))
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)```
````

Comment: Можно результат выполнения кода селениума складывать в какие-нибудь очереди, а бот из очереди будет забирать задания и делать то, что нужно

Comment: await asyncio.to_thread(driver.get, "https://www.google.com/")

Comment: Асинхронный аналог селенимума Playwright.

Answer (score 0):

**1**. Самый **простой и надёжный вариант**: всё таки **разделить код и запускать отдельно**. Локально в разных консолях спокойно запустится, на сервере **systemd** (как пример) для каждого файла, и всё так же успешно будет паралельно работать, тем более раз selenium никак не взаимодействует с кодом бота.

**2**. Если принципиально в одном проекте, то есть библиотека **aioselenium**. Она давно не обновлялась, но можете рассмотреть как альтернативу для selenium.

Не рационально прибегать к потокам в данном случае.

Comment: Проблема в том что в селениуме мне тоже нужно отправлять сообщение юзеру через тг бота, а как мы знаем 2 бота запускать нельзя, aioselenium не подходит.  Все же нужно как-то через потоки это правильно сделать

Comment: Можно отправлять нужную информацию не напрямую в бот, а например в файл, как вариант сохранить в json, или ещё проще в txt, а в боте уже прописать асинхронный цикл на проверку содержимого файла, и в случае изменения отправлять информацию через бот. Более чем уверен эта задача может обойтись без потоков, и соответственно меньше проблем будет в последствии.